# How to Edit Text Anywhere with Your Favorite Editor in Linux?

Tags: x11, xorg, keyboard-shortcuts, emacs, openbox

Editors like emacs or vim has efficient keybindings. How do I edit every text editing field of all applications which them?
There is one for windows already.
http://www.listary.com/text-editor-anywhere
The alternative is to make emacs keybinding work everywhere. See this question.
https://superuser.com/questions/993950/how-do-i-make-emacs-key-bindings-work-everywhere-in-linux

Comment: You can't do this in Linux. Unlike Windows, input editing is not part of the OS, it's implemented by libraries, and different applications can use different libraries.

Comment: OK. Maybe an keybinding for automatic cut and paste from a dedicated emacs buffer.

Comment: For programs you run from a terminal, you can set `$EDITOR` to `emacsclient`, and enable the server in your `.emacs`.

Comment: @Barmar, I normally just run the ansi-term inside emacs.

Comment: I'm talking about programs like `crontab -e` which need to open up a new editor.